# Identityserver4, parameter question. Authorization code flow

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I'm implementing a straight out of the box solution using IDserver4(2.3) targeting .netcore 2.2 that communicates with a FHIR client by calling: 
Url/api/openid/openapp?launch=12345t6u-34o4-2r2y-0646-gj6g123456t5&iss=myservice&launchOrganization=tilt
with some HL7 simulated scopes etc. The flow is okay all the way to the token endpoint serving access and id tokens using the quickstart on an IIS with  certificates and all the bezels.

My problem lies in that the client requires a parameter to be passed to the external client pointing to a file or something on the server where I have some test patient data stored/or served as Json.

Any competent way to pass a parameter with the body or the header for example? And do you do it at the authorization or the authentication, or along with the tokens? Lets call it context. The service shut me down when i reach it. Says this on their side 'TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined'

Thanks in advance.
Got it using:

```
public class CustomClaimInjection : ICustomTokenRequestValidator
{
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;

    public CustomClaimInjection(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContext = contextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }

    public Task ValidateAsync(CustomTokenRequestValidationContext context)
    {
        var client = context.Result.ValidatedRequest.Client;
        //client.Claims.Add(new Claim("sub", sub));  // this will be [client_sub]

        context.Result.CustomResponse = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"example-launchcontext", "https://url/" }
    };

        return Task.CompletedTask;

        //return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: "My problem lies in that the client requires a parameter to be passed to the external client"
Juts to clarify, "the client" is the server with ID4 and "the external client" is the OIDC client?

Also "Url/api/openid/openapp?launch=12345t6u-34o4-2r2y-0646-gj6g123456t5&iss=myservice&launchOrganization=tilt" is the redirect_uri for the "external_client" right?

Comment: @Randy In my flow I open up with a request from a program on my side that calls a launchid: h t t p s://theirservice/api/openid/openapp?launch=123&iss=https://myIdentityserverinstance/&launchorganisation=mycompany. After they come back for a preset metadata link that contains my authorizations and token endpoint, then -> login -> get token (and in my case pass a launchcontext refering to the patient I want the information on). The first I see of the refirect_uri comes after the initial call, the url when I get to the login screnn of my service.

Comment: Looks like this ish at the ID4 server login: h t t p s://myids4/account/login?ReturnUrl=url/connect/authorize/callback?response_type=code&client_id=123&scope=openid patient/*.read launch&redirect_uri=h t t p s://theiradress/api/openid/redirect&aud=https://myids4&launch=123&state=2222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your problem now, and I think you would like a successful authentication to return additional information about where the patient's file is stored. I would store this in the token as a claim since it can be expressed as a statement about the subject (the user). This can be done in the registered (through dependency injection) implementation of the IProfileService. In the implementation of 'GetProfileDataAsync' you can set the issued claims using the 'ProfileDataRequestContext' parameter's property 'IssuedClaims'. These claims will be used to populate the id token which is what you should be looking to do.

Comment: Thanks, that might work as well. I actually had it working with the code above. I just don't know how to mark it as answered. By passing it along with the token with: context.Result.CustomResponse = new Dictionary<string, object>{
{"launchcontext", "patientIdlaunchcontext" } }; I could try this way but it ain't on my priorities right now.